# Loading bitmaps with async task and setting imageview

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am attempting to follow this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html and what I am trying to understand is how to actually load a bitmap using this class. I copied and pasted the code for the BitmapWorkerTask class, and it says to create a new task and execute it using this code:

```
public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
    task.execute(resId);
}
```

I want to load a bitmap in a different java file and then set an imageview to that loaded bitmap, but I don't understand how I actually use the BitmapWorkerTask to actually do that.

Activity where I want to load the bitmap:

```
public class SecondTab extends Fragment {
    ImageView p1;
    ImageView p2;
    ImageView p3;
    ImageView p4;
    ImageView p5;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_secondtab, container, false);
    p1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.p1);
    p2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.p2);
    p3 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.p3);
    p4 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.p4);
    p5 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.p5);

;
        loadBitmap(R.drawable.plane1, p1);
    loadBitmap(R.drawable.plane2, p2);
    loadBitmap(R.drawable.plane3, p3);
    loadBitmap(R.drawable.plane4, p4);
    loadBitmap(R.drawable.plane5, p5);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}





public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
    task.execute(resId);
}
```

}

Comment: What part don't you understand? The tutorial is very straightforward and self-explanatory. I'm not trying to be condescending, I just don't know which part you're having trouble with.

Comment: I don't understand the usage of loadBitmap. In my other java file where I want to load the images, I pasted the above code and tried to use it to load an image as 'loadBitmap(R.drawable.some_image, some_imageView);' but the imageview is blank and never gets an image.

Comment: loadBitmap is just a wrapper function for creating an AsyncTask that loads a given bitmap resource into an ImageView. Did you copy and paste the code for BitmapWorkerTask into your project? (I would imagine you did as it probably souldn't compile without it, but I'm just checking.)

Comment: after looking more closely I did have to make 1 minor change to the code, under 'doInBackground' the line 'return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100));' had to be changed to 'return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources.getSystem(), data, 100, 100);' because it said cannot resolve method getresources(). could that be the reason why it doesnt seem to work?

Comment: Where are you trying to use this code? If it's from an activity, it should work fine, because `getResources()` is a function of `Context` and can therefore be called from `Activity`. If, however, it's from a `Fragment`, you'll have to call `getActivity().getResources()`. If it's from another location, you'll have to save a reference to some instance of a `Context` object.

Comment: That code is in the BitmapWorkerTask.java file

Comment: That's not how that's intended to be used. You should put `loadBitmap()` in your activities as a helper function. However, if you do want to put `loadBitmap()` in `BitmapWorkerTask`, you should include a `Context` object as an argument.

Comment: I do have loadBitmap() in my activity, but when I call it, the image view is empty

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44288/discussion-between-nathan-walters-and-ez4nick)